# Visibility of a border with three divs

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have 3 divs like shown in my code below. In the first and third div I have background colors assigned. The second div contains a white border. The third div is overlapping the first div. Now I want the second div to overlap the third div, but underlap the first div, as shown in the picture. Is there any way to achieve this only using CSS?

I want a CSS-only solution because the third div can grow, depending on the content, which will be placed inside. Therefore I can't use fix values for the second div's height in order to place the border exactly to the position, where the first and third div meet.

I can solve it using JavaScript calculating the size of the third div and therefore adjusting the height of the second div, but I want to avoid that because of screen loading issues.

```css
.div1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.div2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
}

.div3 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class ="div1"></div>
<div class ="div2"></div>
<div class ="div3"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: This would be much easier, if you could place #2 _into_ #3 - is that an option?

Comment: That would be a good solution. But unfortunately the HTML code is being generated automatically and I don't have access to this. I can only change the CSS or import an external JS file to the whole project.

Comment: you are missing position:relative to div1

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand it right? You will sort it as div1, div2 and div3 respectively. If so, your problem will be solved if you give `position: relative` value for each of the divs. Or `position: relative` verip for div1 only, you won't position other divs

```css
.div1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.div2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
}

.div3 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #000000;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class ="div1"></div>
<div class ="div2"></div>
<div class ="div3"></div>
```

Comment: No, I have three divs (1,2,3). Div 1 is under div 3. Div 3 is under div 2. And now div 2 should be under div 1. I guess there is no solution for this issue using CSS-only.

Comment: Do you want div1 at the bottom, div2 at the top and div3 at the top ? Do i understand correct ?

Comment: I am talking about overlapping content - not the order of the content from top to bottom...

Comment: Sorry. I did understand

Answer (score 0):

use `position: relative;` and not `position: absolute;`